# Return specific fields' data from two different collections

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I have fetched data from a collection-1 and stored 'email' field in a variable. and with that I need to find role from collection-2.Now, I need to return first name, last name from collection-1 and role from collection-2 using python

```
userdetails = mongo.db.user_details
userroles = mongo.db.login_mongo
for item in userdetails.find():
   _id = item['WORK_EMAIL']
   for role in userroles.find({'email': _id}):
       role_of = role['roles']
       fname = item['FIRST_NAME']
       lname = item['LAST_NAME']
<SOME CODE>
return role_of,fname,lname
```

expected: role_of,fname,lname
actual: role is correctly displayed but fname and lname are wrongly mapped i.e. displaying another person's details

Comment: can you add the data returned by he DB ?

Comment: I am getting role=lead, fname= Rao, lname=R but the lead role is for another person Not for Rao. Basically, I want to join two collections (fname and lname are in one table and role in another table where email is common for both collections) and return the data

Comment: Could you please confirm whether `email` is unique for a user role ? You may have multiple entries of the same `email` value in `userroles` collection.

Comment: Yes e-mail is unique.